# Lightning Experience - Error on Standard Page Layout

Tags: page-layout, lightning

I turned on Lightning for one of my customers. On a custom object page layout (view mode), I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught Action failed: ui$inputSelect$controller$doInit [TypeError:
>   Cannot read property 'Additional_Divisions__c' of null] throws at https://cs31.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/g_fD27ilRP19XS8vPQMspA/aura_prod.js:1:27
>       at sz.z.set (https://cs31.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/g_fD27ilRP19XS8vPQMspA/aura_prod.js:293:221)
>       at b.K.set (https://cs31.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/g_fD27ilRP19XS8vPQMspA/aura_prod.js:214:232)
>   ...

Additional_Divisions__c is a multi-picklist.

The only similar issue I found in Salesforce is around Lead : [here](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000IYmmQAG). Unfortunately as a workaround they are simply advising to switch to classic.

Did anyone experience the same thing and can we do something about it ?